# Crystal Reports parameter sending NULL instead of chosen value

Tags: sql-server, parameters, crystal-reports

I have a CR 2008 report reading from SQL Server 2008 R2 that used to contain 3 parameters and worked like a champ. The business requested the addition of a fourth parameter. I added the variable to the stored procedure, tested and got the results I was looking for. I then created the parameter as a static list of values as we do not need all values available. I went to the record select expert and lined up my parameter with the appropriate database field. Ran the report, got an error on an incorrect amount of parameters. Refreshed the database; the report ran but returned no results. Checked my parameter values against the stored procedure. Once again, the stored procedure returned results. Went back to Crystal and viewed the query. Lo and behold, the query is sending in NULL for the new parameter even though a specific value was chosen on the prompt. I even went so far as view a tutorial on adding parameters to be sure I did it correctly. Anyone have any thoughts on why the parameter isn't being read properly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to right click on Database fields from Field Explorer > Database expert > [see this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbCCK.png)

that will surely work coz sometimes crystal reports stored procedure need to be reset or refresh to reflect any changes on the SQl code